# How do I test if my Flask dev server is up?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a test fixture on my Flask app which launches the dev server to test some user interactions. For the first test, I'd like to just insure the server is up. What's the best way of doing this in a generically (without testing for a specific response code)? I was hoping I could use `self.assertTrue(response)`, but that seems to pass even if I change the port.

Here's the test case in question:

```
class TestAuth(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        db.init_app(app)
        return app

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.server_proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [sys.executable, 'run.py'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        time.sleep(5)

    @classmethod
    def TearDownLcass(cls):
        os.kill(cls.server_proc.pid, signal.SIGINT)

    def setUp(self):
        selenium_logger = logging.getLogger(
            'selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection')
        selenium_logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_server_up(self):
        response = self.client.get('http://localhost:5000/')
        self.assertTrue(response)
```

Comment: How did you initialize the `self.client` attribute you use in `test_server_up`?

Comment: @Miguel I believe this is provided by [Flask-Testing](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two different ways to test.

The testing style exposed by `Flask-Testing` does not require a separate server to be started. The `self.client.get` call does not really request a URL from a server, it just routes requests internally into the same process that is running the test.

If you want to work with a separate server, then you cannot use `self.client` to request URLs, in that case you have to use a proper HTTP client. It seems you already instantiated a Selenium browser, so that would work just fine. Replace `self.client.get()` with `self.browser.get()`.

If, on the other side, you don't specifically want to start a separate web server and are okay testing your app using the default facilities provided by Flask and Flask-Testing, then remove all the server process start up code and the Selenium stuff and just use `self.client` to make requests. But be aware that `self.client` is not a real web client, so there is no point in testing if the server is up, because there is no server when testing this way.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. How should I check to see if the server responded? I know I could look for the page title, but I don't want to have to change my tests if I change the page title.

Comment: @raddevon: which approach are you going to use? With `self.client.get()` there is no server, so testing if the server is up makes no sense. With Selenium's `self.browser.get()` if you get a response there is a server, if not I believe you'll get a timeout exception (never tried this so I'm not completely sure).

Comment: I'm switching over to Selenium to properly test if the server is running. So, do I just do a `try` around the `self.browser.get`, and do something like `self.assertTrue(False)` if I get the exception?

Comment: Sure, that should work. I have to ask why you think this is an important test, though. You should concentrate on testing your own code, not the code from your web framework.

Comment: My thought was that, if the server isn't up, I'd prefer to see a test called `test_server_up` instead of just seeing every test that tried to hit the server fail. I guess you're right though. It's probably a fool's errand.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I've tried unsuccessfully to mention you in each of these comments. Not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) to send a request to yourself, or even urllib2. Start your dev server and make the request from another instance pointing to your ip:port.